# Where can i see the new file i created in my workspace?

Tags: java, eclipse, file

I looked at the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#File(java.lang.String)) for the File class and I have a question on the File constructor. Basically what the API said was:

> public File(String pathname)
>       Creates a new File instance by converting the given pathname string into an abstract pathname. If the given string is the empty string, then the result is the empty abstract pathname.
>       Parameters: pathname - A pathname string
>       Throws:
>       NullPointerException - If the pathname argument is null

Say hypothetically in eclipse, I execute this line:

```
File file = new File("hi");
```

I know a new file instance is created with that given pathname "hi". Is there a way of actually seeing where that file is in my workspace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just doing `new File("hi");` will not actually create a new physical file.

When you do `new File("c:\\your\\file\\somewhere")` you have to include a path, if the file does not already exist.

If you want to create a file, you'd have to do something else, like using a `PrintWriter`:

```
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("yourfilename.txt", "UTF-8");
writer.println("write something to your file");
writer.close();

// now you can open the file
File yourFile = new File("yourfilename.txt");

// to display it's location on the hard drive
System.out.println(yourFile.getAbsolutePath());
```

Comment: If you run the code I supplied, you will see that the file created with printwriter will located in the root of your project.

Answer (score 0):

The default file location (when no path is specified) using eclipse will be the project folder. It is the same level as .classpath and .project files.

Comment: Under src? Or Jre System library?

Answer (score 0):

The file doesn't usually appear until you refresh your Java project.

Comment: I refreshed it. which section?